Using generic FTDI UART TTL converter for MSP430 bootloader
I’m planning to use the FTDI USB-TTL converter to program my MSP430FR5739 using UART. I wanted to use the “BSL scripter” tool provided by TI, but while reading the manual, I came across this: “BSL Scripter v3.1.0.x doesn’t support communication with MSP430 BSL devices without an MSP-BSL (Rocket) or MSP-FET.”
I feel like this statement is only valid for invoking BSL using hardware (It makes sense since the RST and TEST pins have a specific sequence in order to enter BSL mode).
I am planning to invoke the BSL inside my application code.
My question is:
Can I software invoke BSL then use the BSL scripter to program the microcontroller? Or do I have to buy the MSP-BSL or MSP-FET Tool?
Has anyone tried using the BSL as I’m thinking of?
Does the BSL scripter give an error when it realises that the hardware bridge isn't a MSP-FET or MSP-BSL?
Thank you in advance.
